# What's the difference between * and html in css selector

Tags: css, selector

In css, what's the difference of two selector: * and html?

```
*{

}
```

and

```
html{

}
```

Do these two work differently?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors

Comment: "_Do these two work differently?_" Why do you think they do or don't? What research have you done?

Comment: I got confused since I thought all the elements are inside <html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `*{}` selects all elements and all it's children elements where `html{}` only selects the `<html>` element

See example

```css
html {
    border: solid 2px orange;
}

* {
    border: solid 2px green;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Now see even how the font gets bigger cause its `em` which will take the size from the previous element.

Comment: @kathy all elements will be inside `<html>` but with `*` you assign rules to every single element. See the updated answer, maybe that helps

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you very much!